# Thread Start causing OOM Exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, out-of-memory, prism

```
Thread splashScreenThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DisplaySplashScreen));
splashScreenThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
splashScreenThread.IsBackground = true;
splashScreenThread.Start(moduleName);
```

The above code after being executed 30 to 50 times crashes with an OutOfMemoryException.

If I try splashScreenThread.Join when the DisplaySplashScreen function closes, then the application hangs.

UPDATE:

Development machine is a 64 bit machine and the application under question is a 32 bit WPF application using PRISM.

**Everytime a module is opening the splash window is shown. When the module has opened then the splash window is closed.**

```
private void DisplaySplashScreen(object moduleName)
        {
            if (moduleName != null)
                splashScreen = new SplashWindow(moduleName.ToString(), this.SplashScreenDescription);
            else
                splashScreen = new SplashWindow(string.Empty, string.Empty);

            splashScreen.ShowDialog();
        }
```

NOTE: SplashWindows is custom Window which is shown and closed later automatically.

Module loading start and loaded end fns:

```
private void ModuleLoadingStart(object moduleName)
        {
            if (this.ModuleLoadingVisibility != Visibility.Visible)
            {
                this.ModuleLoadingVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

                // Spawn off a new thread
                Thread splashScreenThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DisplaySplashScreen));
                splashScreenThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                splashScreenThread.IsBackground = true;
                splashScreenThread.Start();
            }
        }



private void ModuleLoadingEnd()
        {
            if (this.ModuleLoadingVisibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                this.ModuleLoadingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                while (true)
                {
                    if (splashScreen == null)
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    else
                        break;
                }

                CloseSplashScreenDelegate myDel = new CloseSplashScreenDelegate(splashScreen.Close);

                splashScreen.Dispatcher.Invoke(myDel, null);
            }
        }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How many threads are running in your application at the time of exception? and what is the memory taken by the process?

Comment: I would say that you probably need to post the code to `DisplaySplashScreen` as there may be memory leaks in that method

Comment: Impossible to say from the posted code, but you are probably missing the equivalent [of this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/SplashScreen.cs,57538949b88b042f).

Comment: @HansPassant you are supposing the error lies in the SplashWindow not freeing up resources. I was thinking that the splashScreenThread was not closed properly.

Comment: Your `DisplaySplashScreen` method creates a new `SplashWindow` instance and then shows it using `ShowDialog`.  A form shown with `ShowDialog` is _not_ automatically disposed when it is closed.  You will need to dispose of these forms somewhere.  What is the purpose of the splash screen anyway?  Is it meant to be visible while some operation is occurring and then closed when the operation is complete?

Comment: The splashScreen is to indicate loading of modules. It is closed using "splashScreen.Close()" when the module is loaded. Should it be disposed too?

Answer (score 0):

WTF are you instantiating so many threads for?! Do you know that `Thread`s are memory hungry beasts. Each one takes up many megabytes of continuous ram!

Anyways. You say that

> If I try splashScreenThread.Join when the DisplaySplashScreen function closes, then the application hangs.

This is pretty simple to diagnose. The problem here is that you have gotten `Thread.Join` completely wrong.

The point of `Thread.Join` is to block (stop everything and wait) the current thread until the work on the other `Thread` is complete. The issue here is that `splashScreenThread` is in a loop. Specifically looping over the display code. So it will NEVER complete. Hence you have told your main thread to wait and do nothing until forever.

Comment: *Each one takes up many megabytes of continuous ram* ? What if a no from me? It takes only one mega byte of ram(committed) in .net by default.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel running under x86 I presume.

Comment: I am not using Join. I just tried it and it was not the way to go.

Comment: I am testing with a Windows 8 64 bit machine and the WPF application under question is a 32 bit application.

Comment: That doesn't makes any different in how much memory a thread takes up. I guess the problem is either too many threads are running, that could fail with OOM even though you still have enough memory. Simply put: we can't answer this question with just what is provided.